# Understanding Account Balances On E*TRADE

Tags: brokerage, assets

I am brand new to E*TRADE and so far I love it, but the setup is a little different to what I'm used to. Could someone explain what the different balances mean? Here's what I'm seeing:

Net Account Value       $173.49,
Total Market Value of Securities        -$135.50,
Cash Available for Investment       $8.99,
Cash Available for Withdrawal       $8.99,
Net Cash Balance    $308.99

Many thanks,

Answer (score 7):

With just that detail, here's all I can tell you:

- You have cash in your account of $308.99
- Of that cash, $8.99 is available to invest or withdraw (you apparently need to keep $300 in cash either for margin or per their policy)
- You have investments that have a net value of -$135.50

  - Either you sold something short and it would cost you 135.50 to buy it back and close your position, or you bought something with leverage that has lost more value than what you paid for it. (or something else that you have to pay to close)
- You net account value is therefore $173.49 ($308.99 - $135.50)

If you sold short or bought with leverage and don't understand what you did (e.g. sold short based on Reddit posts), get out now. Don't invest in anything you don't understand, or you may be risking more money than you put in.

Comment: I'd go with a short position that costs $135.50 to buy to close.

Comment: Yeah that was my guess too - shorting the most recent reddit stonk :).

Comment: I read 'stonker' posts and it amazes me how so many haven't the slightest clue that stock markets correct and that meme stocks correct even more, if not collapse.  YOLO is a great plan for losing it all :->)